# Bigquery SELECT * WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT value) does not work

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a bigQuery table with 30+ columns and I want to `SELECT *` where `session` is unique.

I've been to almost all questions regarding this subject in StackOverflow but none helped me to achieve the expect result.

I've tried `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT session) FROM table.id` but the problem is that returns only `session` column and I need the whole row.

Then I tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM `table.id`
WHERE session IN (
    SELECT session
    FROM `table.id`
    GROUP BY session
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
)
```

But it returns much less rows then `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT sessions)`

So by logic I tried:
`SELECT *, COUNT(DISTINCT sessions)` and `SELECT * WHERE COUNT(DISTINCT sessions)`

none works

Anyone can help? Thanks in advance and kind regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to SELECT * where session is unique ...

Use below instead - note use of `=` in `COUNT(*) = 1`

```
SELECT *
FROM `table.id`
WHERE session IN (
    SELECT session
    FROM `table.id`
    GROUP BY session
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
)
```

Comment: the `<` in my query was a typo... I just run your solution I got 880 entries, and when I run `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT sessions)` I get 936... I'm having a hard time to understand that `HAVING COUNT(*) < 2` - does not mach the values either

Comment: do you have any streaming into this table?

Comment: I'm not sure what is streaming, but I just look the meaning and I don't think so, the source of the data is my backend that sends the hits and that's it, and I'm using this table to create reports.

Comment: in another words  - do you have new entries coming from your backend into your table while you are running your queries?

Comment: yep! I do have new entries coming :)

Comment: so I think this explains it - right? you can test/prove this  - by making a copy of your table and trying the code against this new static table

Answer (score 1):

You query seems alright with `HAVING COUNT(*) = 1` as suggested by @Mikhail.
What wrong is that you are trying to match this result with `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT sessions)`.
Note that `DISTINCT` is used to show distinct records including 1 record from duplicate too. On the other hand `HAVING COUNT(*) = 1` is checking only records which are not duplicate.

For a simple example, if session has :  1, 1, 2, 3

 `DISTINCT` will result in:  1, 2, 3

 `HAVING COUNT(*) = 1` will result in:  2, 3

 hence the difference you see in both result.

Comment: Hey @Vijay can you teach me how I can get the results with distinct? I really need them I don't want them to be exclude from my data... I tried to write `COUNT (DISTINCT customerToken)` instead of `HAVING COUNT(*) < 2` but it did not worked